# Combine two tables in R

Tags: r

I have 2 tables and need to combine them using R as follows:-

```
Table 1

id
A
B
C
D

Table 2

group class
1     X
2     Y
```

I need a combined table like this:-

```
id group class
A  1     X
B  1     X
C  1     X
D  1     X
A  2     Y
B  2     Y
C  2     Y
D  2     Y
```

I tried many types of merges (like inner, left, full join etc) by creating dummy columns in the tables, but couldn't get the desired output. Any help will be of great help

Comment: Looks like an `expand.grid` operation on the row numbers.

Comment: *I tried many types of merges* - Please show your attempts in the question. You will get more help if you *provide broken code to fix* than if you ask others to write code for you from scratch.

Comment: I was using inner_join, full_join etc from dplyr. The answer by Tim Biegeleisen below solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a cross join between the two tables:

```
t1 <- data.frame(id=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
t2 <- data.frame(group=c(1, 2), class=c("X", "Y"))

merge(t1, t2, all=TRUE)

   id group class
1  A     1     X
2  B     1     X
3  C     1     X
4  D     1     X
5  A     2     Y
6  B     2     Y
7  C     2     Y
8  D     2     Y
```

### Demo